# php ipn custom variable not working

Tags: php, paypal

I have this button:

```
 <button name="pay">BUY FOR 0.50$</button>
```

when clicked it inserts a payment with $0 paid, the buyer IP and an account detail into DB:

```
$connect->query("INSERT INTO payments(ip,payed,acc,showed) VALUES('$ip','$payed', '$s', '$h')");

   echo '
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="formsend" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value='.$paypal.'>
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="LOL ACC">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.50">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?=$ip;?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
  <input type="submit" name="sub" class="sub" />
</form>
   ';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('formsend').submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
</script>
```

After that it automatically clicks a new form to go to payment, if Paypal works fine. But then on the IPN the variable `custom` is not passing the IP address.

This is inside the IPN verified part:

```
require_once("config/config.php");
$connect =  new mysqli($server['database']['host'],$server['database']['username'],$server['database']['password'],$server['database']['db']);

// PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!

$ip = $_POST['custom'];
$check = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM payments WHERE ip='$ip' AND payed = 0");

if($check->num_rows){
  $connect->query("UPDATE payments SET payed = 1 WHERE ip = '$ip'");
}
```

I also tried for it to insert a random string, but that doesn't seem to work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: php inside single quotes - `echo '... <?=$ip;?> ...'` is not parsed. You can verify this by looking at the page source code before submitting the form to paypal. Try changing to `echo '<form ... name="custom" value="'.$ip.'"> ... </form>';`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the `<?php` and `?>` inside *single quotes*, it will not be parsed. In order to do this, you should use the string concatenation operators, like so:

```
echo '<form...>
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $ip . '">
</form>';
```